# Command.ExecuteNonQuery() return always -1

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem when I executed Select command in C# using ExecuteNonQuery() method; It always return -1; This means that no record returned by the selected statement, doesn't it?

But when i open sql managment studio and run the same select statement; I found that it returned rows.

Please help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't execute a `SELECT with an ExecuteNonQuery()`.  It is called ExecuteNonQuery because you want something to execute that is not a query.  A `SELECT` is a query.  You want to ExecuteReader.  If you want to do an `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, then you can do an `ExecuteNonQuery()` and that will show how many rows were affected.

Answer (score 6):

No, that indicates that it *affected* no rows.

From the docs for [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of statements, the return value is -1**. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Perhaps you're looking for [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) instead? That's appropriate for - say - fetching a count. It returns a single value from the query. Otherwise (if you want actual results), use [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx) to fetch "normal" results.

A SELECT statement is a query in SQL, so it's really unclear why you'd try to execute one with `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: If he wants rows returned the ExecuteScalar is not the way to do it. ExecuteScalar returns the first column in the first row.

Comment: @Sani: Yes - it wasn't clear to me what he actually *did* want. That's why I mentioned both ExecuteScalar and ExecuteReader.

Comment: Edited answer much better... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ExecuteReader()` OR `SqlDataAdapter()` for fetching rows.

Comment: i don't need to fetch any rows; what i want to know only that i have a result from my select statment:here my code:        SqlConnection conn = getConnection();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

            

        command.CommandText = //here select statment with parameters
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromDate", _DateFrom);
              command.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

        conn.Close();

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` is used when you are performing nonquery operations like `insert, update or delete`, it can't be used for query operation like `select`. In order to fetch records from `DB`, use `SqlDataReader` or `SqlDataAdapter` but `SqlDataReader` gives better performance. Have a look at this link describing [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx).